# Brunch js check module exists before require

Tags: javascript, brunch

Using brunch I'm trying to do a check for if a module exists before trying to require it to stop an error.

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "xxxxx"

```
if(require("filename")){
   require("filename"); 
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What are you expecting the second call to require("filename") to do that the first one didnt?

Comment: yeah. use `try-catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a try-catch to stop it from erroring.